# Jekyll Git hub pages no styles applied

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I would like to say that I have been looking at this problem for the past two hours, reviewing similar questions. I can not seem to find the issue, Initially I thought it was due to my baseurl and the file path for the css. Everything is styled perfectly on my local server.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can give me some pointers.  My git hub repo is https://github.com/Nappolini/nappolini-port

Many thanks.

Comment: Please do not expect people to go through your Github repository and search for all necessary information. Please create a (minimal example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. This helps you a lot getting answers to your question.

Comment: I'm ok with the minimal example requirement. But sometimes, it's better to see whole code in order to spot the problem. And, showing all site code in SO makes questions unreadable. Nevertheless, we have an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In **_config.yml** set :

```
baseurl: /nappolini-port
url: https://nappolini.github.io/
```

In **_layouts/default.html**, call assets with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css">
```

Comment: Thank you both for the help, David I pasted in the below as per your suggestion        ```css <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}../assets/css/main.css"> ```

Comment: It works perfectly on my local server but not on git hub pages. The file path for the css on the local server is correct and am stumpt on why it will not work with git hub pages.

Comment: Jekyll is serving locally at **127.0.../** aka **"the root"**. If you set `baseurl: /nappolini-port` jekyll will serve from **127.0...//nappolini-port/**, just like it will do on gh-pages. That's where, setting up your development environment as close as other environments, matters.

Comment: On my local server port: 3001 the following code works ```baseurl: /nappolini-port/ `` if i remove the slash the css styles are not applied. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it. Does gh automatically know to use the content of _site as the build folder?  Thanks for the help

Comment: `baseurl: /nappolini-port` no trailing slash.

Comment: you should use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css//main.css" | relative_url }}">` who will prefix the path with `site.baseurl`or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css//main.css" | absolute_url }}">` who will prefix the path with `site.url/site.baseurl`